# Mining from monero-wallett-cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, cpu-mining, mining, monerod-commands

I have a question about mining with **moderod**. If I mine from monerod, I must specify wallet address and cpu core to use, but if I mine from **monero-wallet-cli**, a `'start_mining'` command is enough.

So, my question is:

*mining from wallet, do the mined coins go straight to the wallet? Is it right?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any mining rewards will go to the wallet from which you executed the `start_mining` command.